# How to calculate the pH of a redox reaction between nickel(IV) oxide and silver?

Tags: redox, solutions, reduction-potential

> For the following reaction:
> \begin{gather}
> \ce{NiO2(s) + 4 H+(aq) + 2 Ag(s) -> Ni^2+(aq) + 2H2O(l) + 2Ag+(aq)}\\
> E^\circ = \pu{2.48 V}
> \end{gather}
>
> Calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution if $E = \pu{2.23 V}$ and $[\ce{Ag+}] = [\ce{Ni^2+}] = \pu{0.023 mol/l}$.

I know that there is the Nernst equation:
$$E = E^\circ-\left(0.0592/n\right)\log Q$$
Where $E^\circ$ is the standard cell potential, $E$ is the cell potential for non-standard conditions, and at non-standard pressures or concentrations,
$$Q = \frac{[\text{products}]}{[\text{reactants}]}.$$

I know that for this problem, $n(\ce{e-}) = 4\ \mathrm{mol}$, and that
$$Q = \frac{[0.023]^3}{[\ce{H+}]^4}.$$

So:
\begin{align}
  2.23 
  &= 2.48 - \frac{0.0592}{4}\log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H+}]^4}\right)
  \tag{1}\\
  0.25 
  &= \frac{0.0592}{4}\log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H+}]^4}\right)
  \tag{2}\\
  1.00 
  &= \frac{0.0592}{1}\log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H+}]^4}\right)
  \tag{3}\\
  1.00 
  &= 0.0592\log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[H^+]^4}\right)
  \tag{4}\\
  \frac{1.00}{0.0592} 
  &= \log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H+}]^4}\right)
  \tag{5}\\
  \frac{1.00}{0.0592} 
  &= \log(0.023^3)-\log\left([\ce{H+}]^4\right)
  \tag{6}\\
  \frac{1.00}{0.0592} - \log(0.023^3)
  &= -\log\left([\ce{H+}]^4\right)
  \tag{7}\\
  \frac{1.00}{0.0592} - \log(0.023^3) 
  &= -4\log\left([\ce{H+}]\right)
  \tag{8}\\
  \frac{\frac{1.00}{0.0592} - \log(0.023^3)}{4} 
  &= -\log\left([\ce{H+}]\right)
  \tag{9}\\
  \mathrm{pH} &= -\log\left([\ce{H+}]\right)
  \tag{10}\\
  \frac{\frac{1.00}{0.0592} - \log\left(0.023^3\right)}{4} 
  &= 5.45
  \tag{11}
\end{align}

Therefore, $$\mathrm{pH} = 5.45\tag{12}.$$

Yet, the online assignment here says my answer is wrong.

[image: This is what I mean]

It even gives me practice versions for other variations of this problem, and yet I still always get a wrong answer using the same methods.  Would someone be so kind as to point out any errors I may have made while calculating this answer?

Answer (score 4):

> For the following reaction:
> \begin{gather}
> \ce{NiO2(s) + 4 H+(aq) + 2 Ag(s) -> Ni^2+(aq) + 2 H2O(l) + 2 Ag^+(aq)}\\
> E^\circ = \pu{2.48 V}
> \end{gather}
> Calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution if $E = \pu{2.23 V}$ and $[\ce{Ag^+}] = [\ce{Ni^2+}] = \pu{0.023 M}$.

The important thing to understand that was not immediately obvious to me and a lot of other people was the fact that $n = 2$, and this changes how you calculate your answer.

$\ce{Ni}$ does not change oxidation state in its transition from $\ce{NiO2}$ to $\ce{Ni^2+}$, as its oxidation state in $\ce{NiO2}$ is $+2$.  The 4 $\ce{H^+}$ ions also do not change oxidation state in their transition from $\ce{H^+}$ to $\ce{H2O}$, oxidation state in $\ce{H^+}$ is $+1$ and oxidation state in $\ce{H2O}$ for $\ce{H}$ is $+1$ for 2 $\ce{H}$ atoms.  That leaves us with the only $\ce{e^-}$ transfer occurring to $\ce{Ag}$.  There are 2 moles of $\ce{Ag}$ atoms going to oxidation state $+1$.  Therefore, 2 moles of $\ce{e^-}$ are transferred.  Hence, $n=2$

The Nernst Equation:
$$E = E^\circ  -  (0.0592/n)\log Q$$
Where $E˚$ is the standard cell potential, $E$ is the cell potential for non-standard conditions, and at non-standard pressures or concentrations, $$Q = \frac{[\text{products}]}{[\text{reactants}]}.$$

For this problem, $n(\ce{e-}) = \pu{2 mol}$, and that
$$Q = \frac{[0.023]^3}{[\ce{H^+}]^4}.$$

Following the above calculation with this difference leads to $\mathrm{pH} = 3.34$, which is the [correct solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0sLE.png).

\begin{align}
\tag1  
2.23 &= 2.48 
- \frac{0.0592}{2}\log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H^+}]^4}\right)\\
\tag2 
0.25 &= \frac{0.0592}{2} \log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H^+}]^4}\right)\\
\tag3 
0.50 &= \frac{0.0592}{1} \log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H^+}]^4}\right)\\
\tag4 
0.50 &= 0.0592\log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H^+}]^4}\right)\\
\tag5 
\frac{0.50}{0.0592} &= \log\left(\frac{0.023^3}{[\ce{H^+}]^4}\right)\\
\tag6 
\frac{0.50}{0.0592} 
&= \log\left(0.023^3\right) -\log\left([\ce{H^+}]^4\right)\\
\tag7 
\frac{0.50}{0.0592} - \log\left(0.023^3\right) 
&= -\log\left([\ce{H^+}]^4\right)\\
\tag8 
\frac{0.50}{0.0592} - \log\left(0.023^3\right) 
&= -4\log\left([\ce{H^+}]\right)\\
\tag9 
\frac{\frac{0.50}{0.0592} - \log\left(0.023^3\right)}{4} 
&= -\log\left([\ce{H^+}]\right)\\
\tag{10} 
\mathrm{pH} &= -\log\left([\ce{H^+}]\right)\\
\tag{11} 
\frac{\frac{0.50}{0.0592} - \log\left(0.023^3\right)}{4} &= 3.34
\end{align}

Comment: Nice work!  We like questions where the asker is actually engaged.

Answer (score 0):

For your future assignment it is always worth work with two half-reactions: oxidation and reduction: Given is:

$$\ce{NiO2(s) + 4 H+(aq) + 2 Ag(s) -> Ni^2+(aq) + 2 H2O(l) + 2 Ag^+(aq)}\quad
E^\circ = \pu{2.48 V}$$

Oxidation half-reaction:
$$\ce{Ag (s) <=> Ag+ + e-} \tag1$$
Reduction half-reaction:
$$\ce{NiO2 (s) + 4 H+ + 2e- <=> Ni^2+ + 2H2O (l)} \tag2$$
To cancell electrons, add $(1) + 2\times(2)$:
$$\ce{NiO2(s) + 4 H+(aq) + 2 Ag(s) -> Ni^2+(aq) + 2 H2O(l) + 2 Ag^+(aq)}\quad
\tag3$$

Now you know the number of cancelling $\ce{e-}$ is $2$. Thus, $n = 2$ for the Nernst equation. Thus, you would never miss it again.